# Printing Stars in java

Tags: java

```
public static void processQuestionData()
{
   double[] cake = {3.6, 7.8, 15.8}
   double carrot = 15.8

   for (int i = 0; i < cake.length; i++)
    {

        drawBar(cake[i], carrot);

    }

public static void drawBar(double value, double max )
{
    final int MAX_STARS = 20
    String BAR_REP = "*";

    double correctRatio = (value / max) * MAX_STARS;

    if (correctRatio == MAX_STARS)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_STARS; index++)
        {
            System.out.print(BAR_REP);
        }
    }

    else if (correctRatio < MAX_STARS)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_STARS; index++)
        {
            System.out.print(BAR_REP);
        }
    }
}
```

I want given a value and a max as double type arguments, draws a bar using * representing the value, scaled so that max value would equal the constant MAX_STARS. I am not able to do that what is wrong with my code?

```
 Output should be
 ****
 *********
 ********************
```

1st star gotten by (3.6 / 15.8) * 20 = 4

3rd star gotten by (15.8 / 15.8) * 20 = 20

How can I do that?

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: Yes what is the problem?

Comment: Note: instead of printing `"*"` n times, you could create a `char[]` of the appropriate size and `Arrays.fill()` it with `'*'`; you'd then `System.out.print(new String(theCharArray))` (and by the way, why `print` and not `println`?)

Answer (score 0):

**A FEW CHANGES IN YOUR CODE WILL MAKE IT RUN PROPERLY:**

I feel that your code may not be displaying the output correctly because of the missing System.out.println(); statement (that I have added in the last line of the code). Also the conditional checking you were performing was redundant. Instead of checking for = and < seperately you can check for <= in one block itself.

```
public static void processQuestionData()
{
   double[] cake = {3.6, 7.8, 15.8};
   double carrot = 15.8;

   for (int i = 0; i < cake.length; i++){
            drawBar(cake[i], carrot);
   }

}

public static void drawBar(double value, double max ){
    final int MAX_STARS = 20;
    String BAR_REP = "*";

    double correctRatio = (value / max) * MAX_STARS;

    if (correctRatio <= MAX_STARS){
        for (int index = 0; index < correctRatio; index++){
            System.out.print(BAR_REP);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works:

```
public static void drawBar(double value, double max )
{
    final int MAX_STARS = 20;

    final double ratio = value / max;
    if (Double.compare(ratio, 1.0) > 0)
        return;
    final int nrElements = (int) (ratio * MAX_STARS);
    final char[] array = new char[nrElements];
    Arrays.fill(array, '*');

    System.out.println(new String(array));
}
```

Note:

- `MAX_STARS` could be a `private static final int` at the class level;
- it is not checked whether `value / max` is greater than 1;
- if you want to make comparisons between `double` values, you should use `Double.compare()` as shown above; some legal `double` values are not `==` to one another, for instance `Double.NaN`;
- you could even optimize that further by creating a `private static final` array of 20 stars, using a `writer` and print a subarray each time.